# Is there an efficient and elegant way to truncate number like this in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

### What I want to do

What I want to do is really simple. I want use Lua to check lines in a Plist file.

Let's say if a line in Plist, is `<integer>-1.00</integer>`, I need to cut the `.00` off to make it be `<integer>-1</integer>`.

### What I did

I use a function to read the whole file content and do line by line check and replace.

```
local function doLineClean( cont )
    newcont = ''
    string.gsub( cont, "(.-)\r?\n", function(line)
        if string.match( line, "<integer>.-<%/integer>" ) then
            string.gsub( line, "<.->(.-)<.->", function(v)
            a, b = string.find(v,"%..*")
            if a and b then
                v = string.sub( v, 0, a - 1 )
            end
            line = "\t\t<integer>"..v.."</integer>"
            end  )
        end
        newcont = newcont .. line .. '\n'
    end  )
    return newcont
end
```

### My question

Is there an more efficient and elegant way to do the same job?

Comment: To be clear, you want not just `-1.00` to be `-1`, but all floating point numbers inside of `<integer>` element to be truncated? What if it is `-1.99`?

Comment: @Phrogz yes, truncate all floats, `-1.99` should be `-1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that Lua's string patterns are not full regular expressions. They are more limited and less powerful, but usually sufficient (as in this case).

Why not a far simpler replacement such as the following?

```lua
local s1 = [[
<integer>3</integer>
<integer>3.12</integer>
<integer>-1.00</integer>
<integer>-1.99</integer>
<float>3.14</float>
]]

local s2 = s1:gsub('(<integer>%-?%d+)%.%d+','%1')
print(s2)
--> <integer>3</integer>
--> <integer>3</integer>
--> <integer>-1</integer>
--> <integer>-1</integer>
--> <float>3.14</float>
```

This finds:

1. the text `<integer>`,
2. optionally followed by a literal hyphen (`%-?`)
3. followed by one or more digit characters (`%d+`)
4. followed by a literal period (`%.`)
5. followed by one or more digit characters (`%d+`)

and replaces it with the first capture (the contents of 1-3, above).

Note that this will not work if you can have floats without a leading digit (e.g. `<integer>.99</integer>`) or scientific notation (e.g. `<integer>1.34e7</integer>`).

Comment: Thanks for step by step explain.

Answer (score -2):

That should do the job:

```
s = "<integer>-1.00</integer>"
s:gsub("[.]%d*","")
```

Comment: -1 Presumably this file may have decimal values in other locations that should not be touched, e.g. `<float>3.14</float>` or `<version>1.2.3</version>`. Further, what you have here will also remove raw periods (e.g. `"Hello. Bye!"` will become `"Hello Bye!"`).

Comment: Well the solution is based on the given input. I don't know what other content is in the file. The solution need to be modified in case ...